# Evaluate double integral:

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate:

$$\iint_{D} \arcsin(x^2+y^2)\, dx\,dy$$

where $D$ is defined by the following polar equation $\rho=\sqrt{\sin \theta}$ and $0\le\theta\le\pi$

Comment: it means $sin\theta$ in italian

Comment: O.o looks like I learnt new thing @AméricoTavares

Comment: $\displaystyle\large\rho = \,\sqrt{\,\sin\left(\theta\right)\,}\,$ 'describes a line'.

Answer (score 3):

change it into polar, it changes into 
$$\int_0^\pi \int_0^{\sqrt{\sin\theta}} \arcsin(r^2) r dr d\theta$$

Just evaluate this integral first
$$\int_0^{\sqrt{\sin\theta}} \arcsin(r^2) r dr$$
you can evaluate the indefinite integral using substitution and by parts as 
$$\frac 1 2 \int \arcsin(r^2) d(r^2) = \frac 1 2  \left( \sqrt{1-r^4}+r^2 \sin ^{-1}(r^2) \right)$$
Putting bounds $r = \sqrt{\sin \theta}$ and $r=0$ gives you $\displaystyle \frac 1 2 \left( |\cos \theta| + \arcsin( \sin \left(\theta\right)) \sin\theta \right) - \frac 1 2$ which you will get 
$$\int_0^\pi \frac 1 2 \left( |\cos \theta| + \arcsin( \sin \left(\theta\right)) \sin\theta  - 1\right) d\theta  = \frac{4 - \pi}{2}$$
Note that $\cos \theta$ is negative on $\pi/2 \to \pi$ but $\sqrt{1 - \sin^2\theta}$ is always positive. I think you can easily integrate $\theta \sin \theta$ by parts. For $|\cos \theta|$ you can use that fact that 
$$\int_0^{\pi}|\cos\theta|d\theta = 2 \int_0^{\pi/2}\cos\theta d\theta = 2$$
Since $\cos $ is symmetric at middle for interval $(0, \pi)$.
For integral you can use the same argument
$$\int_0^{\pi} \arcsin( \sin \left(\theta\right)) d\theta = 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \theta \sin \theta d\theta = 2$$

Comment: Can you solve it?

Comment: @ILoveMath yep I can :D

Comment: I solved it but the result is not correct as indicated in the school book...i got 3/2...my book writes: $2-\pi/2 $

Comment: @ILoveMath i'll update answer in 5 min

Comment: write results step by step pleaseee...

Comment: @ILoveMath does that help you?

Comment: I think it should be:$$\int_0^{\pi}|\cos\theta|d\theta = 2 \int_0^{\pi/2}\cos\theta d\theta$$

Comment: @ILoveMath sorry about that ... fixed it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14705/discussion-between-santosh-linkha-and-i-love-math).

Comment: i can't talk in chat..

Comment: @ILoveMath sorry ,,, I was moving some other guy to chat. I clicked the link here by mistake.

Comment: i still can't understand how did you get $$2-\pi/2$$ I understood everything except the result of :$$\int_0^\pi \frac 1 2 \left( |\cos \theta| + \theta \sin\theta  - 1\right) d\theta  = \frac{4 - \pi}{2}$$

Comment: @ILoveMath up to which part does it make sense? and after which it doesn't? I'll elaborate it

Comment: Could you evaluate step by step the last integral I wrote?

Comment: I won't be able to answer you anymore because i must go...so i'll see the answer tomorrow...thanks for all

Comment: @ILoveMath I had made some critical error, I have updated the result please check when you are back.

Comment: ohhh...I forgot that the range of usual principal value of $arcsin\theta$ is $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$...so i've made a mistake writing: $$\int_0^{\pi} \arcsin( \sin \left(\theta\right))\sin\theta d\theta =  \int_0^{\pi} \theta \sin \theta d\theta$$

Comment: @ILoveMath nevermind, I forgot too ... :( this problem was very tricky.

Comment: now it all makes sense..XD

Comment: Please keep extended discussions in the chat and out of the comments.